# Why does Visual Studio keep moving back to a breakpoint while I am inspecting?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Set a breakpoint anywhere in the code and from there go look around. For example, move back in the callstack or F12 into some class or member. Within a few seconds Visual Studio moves back to the screen with the breakpoint.

It basically breaks the debugger unless what you need is in the same spot as the breakpoint.

Comment: It probably means that your application just hit that breakpoint?

Comment: It is a quirk in a recent VS2017 update.  They already know about it so a future update will probably fix it.

Comment: Probably this is not the good place to ask this question. Raise an issue to Visual studio developer community from VS IDE itself. From top right corner.

Comment: The difference is if I follow your instruction I submit a plea for assistance into the void. If I come here and ask I get an answer that I can take action on.

Comment: As @HansPassant said, this is a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/313174/visual-studio-158-xamarin-debug-issues.html). It looks like the expect to have it fixed in 15.8.5